# Operands to the && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values:

Tags: matlab, logical-operators, operands

What is the error in this line of code:

```
 if BB(i) <= max([BB(i-4):BB(i)]) && BB(i) <= max([BB(i-7):BB(i)])
```

I get the following error message:

```
??? Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.
Error in ==> if BB(i) <= max([BB(i-4):BB(i)]) && BB(i) <= max([BB(i-7):BB(i)])
```

Comment: Do you have any more information on what `BB` is? Also I'm guessing you actually mean `max(BB((i-4):i))`

Comment: @Suever: BB is a vector. you're right, indeed I mean max(BB((i-4):i)). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to `&`.
`&&` and `||` are shorthand for using *short-circuiting* behavior, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html?searchHighlight=logical%20operators#bt_0nai-1) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html).

Comment: It seems OP does want `&&` here. In fact, using `&` or `|` might conceal potential errors, when a test that is meant to return scalar (as in OP's question) returns an array: If that array has an entry evaluating to `false`, the whole expression is `false` as far as `if` is concerned.